# Check for overlapping date ranges based on a compound key

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have a SQL Server 2008 table with data like this:

```
Contract_No  Property_No  Start_Dte     End_Dte
12345        123          01/01/2014    01/31/2014
12345        123          01/15/2014    02/15/2014
12345        123          03/01/2014    03/31/2014
12345        124          01/01/2014    01/31/2014
```

I cannot have the same Contract/Property # with an overlapping date range. So, the second row above would be a problem since its `Start_Dte` starts in the middle of the 1st row's date range. All other rows are ok.

I'm really at a loss on how to do this with a SQL query. I know how to check for this using a language like C# or VB, but my lousy attempts at writing a query have failed.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following query will show all records that have conflicting date ranges with other records ([**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bae6e/6/0)):

```
WITH x AS (
  SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Contract_No, Property_No, Start_Dte) AS r
  FROM MyTable
)
SELECT * 
FROM x m1
INNER JOIN x m2
ON m2.Contract_No = m1.Contract_No
AND m2.Property_No = m1.Property_No
AND m1.r <> m2.r
AND 
(  
  (
    m2.Start_Dte >= m1.Start_Dte 
    AND m2.Start_Dte <= m1.End_Dte
  ) OR 
  (
    m2.End_Dte >= m1.Start_Dte 
    AND m2.End_Dte <= m1.End_Dte
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

(Edited)

The following query will generate a list of contract/property pairs for which there are two or more overlapping periods:

```
SELECT distinct t1.Contract_No, t1.Property_No, t1.Start_Dte, t1.End_Dte
 from MyTable t1
  inner join MyTable t2
   on t2.Contract_No = t1.Contract_No
    and t2.Property_No = t1.Property_No
    and t1.Start_Dte <> t2.Start_Dte  --  PK check
    and t1.End_Dte <> t2.End_Dte      --  PK check
    and t2.Start_Dte < t1.End_Dte
    and t2.End_Dte > t1.Start_Dte
```

This worked on the sample data provided, but there may yet be fringe cases to take into account, such as...

The ugly hard part is that there's no way to uniquely identify a row in the table without referencing every column... which incidentally means that if two or more rows have identical times, they won't be caught by this query, and you'll need to use one of the other solutions that use `row-number`. (Of course, not having a primary key, you'll have tons of other problems as well...) If there is a primary key available, the two `--  PKcheck` lines can be replaced with a simple primary key check.

As mentioned, I never get this Aztec Math stuff right the first time. Below is my initial pre-debugging response.

---

The following query will generate a list of contract/property pairs for which there are two or more overlapping periods:

```
SELECT distinct t1.Contract_No, t1.Property_No
 from MyTable t1
  inner join MyTable t2
   on t2.Contract_No = t1.Contract_No
    and t2.Property_No = t1.Property_No
    and (t2.Start_Dte > t1.End_Dte
         or t2.End_Dte < t1.Start_Dte)
```

Be sure to test the logic, I always find it tricky to get these temporal queries exactly right on the first go. The idea is

- Either the second contract starts after the first one ends
- Or the second contract ends before the first one starts
- If one of the other does not apply, the periods will overlap

If start/stop dates can overlap, use >= and <=. Be wary if you are using the datetime or smalldatetime datatype -- besides the date, you will also have a time "element" in the value.

That's the start. The next step is listing out all the contract/properties:

```
SELECT tt.*  --  Being lazy here, you should always specify precisely which columns to return
 from MyTable tt
  inner join (--  Make it a subquery
              select distinct t1.Contract_No, t1.Property_No
                from MyTable t1
                inner join MyTable t2
                 on t2.Contract_No = t1.Contract_No
                  and t2.Property_No = t1.Property_No
                  and (t2.Start_Dte > t1.End_Dte
                       or t2.End_Dte < t1.Start_Dte)) xx
   on xx.Contract_No = tt.Contract_No
    and xx.Property_No = tt.Property_No
```

Next up: determine which contract is wrong. That, of course, requires application of business logic, putting the ball back in your court.

Comment: Yes it did. I applied boolean logic, edited my response, and figured it still won't work without a primary key on the table.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Contract_No], [Property_No], [Start_Dte]) AS row_num
  FROM tbl
)
SELECT *
FROM cte t1
WHERE EXISTS(
  SELECT 1 
  FROM cte t2 
  WHERE 
   t1.Contract_No = t2.Contract_No
  AND t1.Property_No = t2.Property_No
  AND t1.row_num > t2.row_num
  AND (
      (t1.Start_Dte BETWEEN t2.Start_Dte AND t2.End_Dte)
        OR 
      (t1.END_Dte BETWEEN t2.Start_Dte AND t2.End_Dte)
  )
)
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c4768/6)